# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, frontend

I have an front-end application on apache server.
When i go to BASE URL it's fine but if go to (Base URL)/example and refresh this show the next message:

Not Found
The requested URL /example was not found on this server.

On my server linux (Centos 7) on /var/www/html have the ".htaccess" file with the next content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Somehelp how resolve this ?
Thank !

Comment: Remove the IfModule wrapper.

Comment: @MrWhite still "not found"

Comment: Are htaccess overrides enabled in the server config?

Comment: @MrWhite you mean the  httpd.conf file ? so...  `<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory> `  and  `<Directory "/var/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: Is that the only Directory container? You should have a Directory container specific to /var/www/html. Try typing *nonsense* at the top of the htaccess file. Do you get an error?

Comment: @MrWhite I have the next wrapper `<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
`

Comment: That should be `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the next wrapper `<Directory "/var/www/html">     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks     AllowOverride None     Require all granted </Directory>`

It looks like `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled for the specific directory you have the `.htaccess` file.

It should be `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` container.

Then restart Apache for the changes to take effect.